# Sending string[] from C# to C++ Dll 'E_UNEXPECTED' 'Catastrophic Error' on SafeArrayAccessData()

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I have c# project and i have to use a C++ dll using DllImport. (I have source codes of c++ dll)

I'm importing a function from c++ dll like this :

```
    [DllImport("Example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int SendRequest(ref string[] fields);
```

I' m using this function in c# like this :

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>();
fields.Add("Test1");
fields.Add("Test2");
string[] fieldsArr = fields.ToArray();

int resultOfSendRequest = SendRequest(ref fieldsArr);
```

The problem is SafeArrayAccessData function on c++ dll returns 'E_UNEXPECTED' 'Catastrophic Error'.

C++ code is like this :

```
__declspec( dllexport ) int _stdcall SendRequest  (SAFEARRAY**);

int _stdcall SendRequest ( SAFEARRAY** arrayFlds)

{   
    int res = 0;
char s[1024], Info[1024];
S_FLDS flds[MAX_FLDS];
HRESULT hRes;

// which language is using thr Dll ?
BYTE* pData; 
hRes = SafeArrayAccessData  (*arrayFlds, (void**)&pData);
BYTE bufLang [] = {0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
Language = (memcmp(bufLang, pData, sizeof(bufLang)) == 0) ? CALLER_VC : CALLER_VB;
hRes = SafeArrayUnaccessData(*arrayFlds);

//...
```

}

**EDIT:** Okay, i solved this by

```
 public static extern int SendRequest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] ref string[] fields);
```

Now the problem is in c++ dll, it casts string to char* in somewhere and it reads the only first character, not entire string.

Comment: Not surprising really. The unmanaged code returns a SAFEARRAY. Your C# does not match. Do some research on how to Marshall SAFEARRAY.

Comment: Okay, i solved error on  SafeArrayAccessData() . Now the problem is in c++ dll, it casts string to char* in somewhere and it reads the only first character, not entire string.

Comment: If you have a new question, don't ask it in an edit to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, i solved this by using :

```
public static extern int SendRequest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)] ref string[] fields);
```